# calculate double negative exponent

Tags: java, double, pow, exponential

I want to know how to calculate this equation in Java considering that the exponent can be negative

equation example:

```
D_DL=10^((149.874-69.55-26.16 log_10(900)+13.82 log_10(60)+1.115)/([44.9-6.55 log_10(60)]))
```

Here I'm trying to calculate my exponent

```
double   exposantD =  ( Mapldl_s - 69.55 -( 26.16 * Math.log10(_BF_) )+ (13.82 * Math.log10(HB_)) + _ahm_)  / (44.9 - (6.55 *Math.log10(HB_)));
```

I try with this function :

```
public static double powMyExpo(double base, double exponent) {
double result = 1;

            if (exponent == 0) {
            return result;
            } 
            if (exponent < 0) {
            return 1 / powMyExpo(base, exponent * -1);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= exponent; i++) {
            result = result * base; 
            }
            return result;
}
```

but always **result = 1**

Thanks

Comment: `Math.pow(base, exponent)` should already be able to handle negative exponents. Why are you trying to implement this on your own? Is this time-critical code?

Comment: I've done some simple tests, and the method is working fine, at least for integer exponents. Please give an example of failing inputs. Also, consider the possibility that the bug is elsewhere, perhaps something making `exponent` zero or `base` one.

Comment: @Marco13 thanks for repaly I was think it does not accept the negative. 
@PatriciaShanahan Yes you are right, my exponent egal to 0.8 which follows that `i > exponent` , I juste use `Math.pow(base, exponent)` and it's fine, 
Thanks